# Pass parameters to AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, builder, android-alertdialog

I was trying to pass some parameters to an AlertDialog, this dialog most show these two parameters (suppose "foo" and "bar" parameters), and I'm calling this dialog using `showDialog(int id)`. There is another method in Activity class which take a `Bundle` object to pass parameters: `showDialog(int id, Bundle args)`, but this method is only available to API 8 or greater and I need to work with API 7.

Here I put some chunks of code to make easier what I am doing.

In my activity I create AlertDialog like this:

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        final LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        switch(id) {
        case DIALOG_ID:
            final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            final TextView fooValue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.foo_label);
            final TextView barValue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.foo_label);
            //fooLabel.setText("HERE MUST BE FOO PARAMETER VALUE");
            //barLabel.setText("HERE MUST BE BAR PARAMETER VALUE");

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
                setIcon(R.drawable.icon).
                setTitle(R.string.app_name).
                setView(view).
                setPositiveButton(R.string.close, null).
                create();
...
```

And in other part I call this dialog:

```
    // THESE PARAMETERS MUST BE PASSED TO DIALOG
    int foo = result.getInt("foo");
    String bar = result.getString("bar");

    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
...
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding a method `setFooBar(int foo, String bar)` to the class that is implementing the `onCreateDialog` function above, to receive the values of foo and bar before `showDialog` is called.

If you do not have an instance of the activity, consider making the method and variables static.

Answer (score -1):

try this example

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);// this layout can created by yourself whatever you want.
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
                .setView(textEntryView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                    }
                })
                .create();
```

layoutname : main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="#663355"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```